# Генерация всех возможных комбинаций из нескольких массивов (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Помогите написать функцию, которая принимает массив из массивов (с числами) и возвращает массив со всеми возможными комбинациями

Например на входе:

```
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2]
];
```

Массив динамический и кол-во элементов первого уровня может меняться равно как и кол-во элементов внутри вложенных массивов.

На выходе должно выдать:

```
[
  111,
  121,
  131,
  141,
  151,
  161,
  171,
  122,
  132,
  142,
  152,
  162,
  172,
  211,
  221,
  231,
  241,
  251,
  261,
  271,
  222,
  232,
  242,
  252,
  262,
  272
]
```

Comment: сделайте поиск по `декартово произведение`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const generateCartesianProduct = (arrays) => {
  const combineArrays = (arr1, arr2) =>
    arr1.flatMap((item1) => arr2.map((item2) => `${item1}${item2}`));

  if (arrays.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  let result = [...arrays[0]];

  for (let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    result = combineArrays(result, arrays[i]);
  }

  return result.map(String);
};

// Пример использования:
const inputArrays = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2]
];

const cartesianProduct = generateCartesianProduct(inputArrays);

console.log(cartesianProduct);
```

Внутри функции есть вложенная функция combineArrays, которая принимает два массива arr1 и arr2 и использует метод [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) для создания массива, содержащего все возможные комбинации элементов из arr1 и arr2, если массив arrays пустой, то функция возвращает пустой массив, инициализируем result как копию первого массива из arrays, используя оператор распространения [...arrays[0]], используем цикл for для комбинирования элементов result с каждым из вложенных массивов, вызывая combineArrays и обновляя result на каждой итерации, возвращаем result, который представляет собой массив со всеми возможными комбинациями.

Comment: переименовал функции и переменные в  коде

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2]
];
const a = []
test()
console.log(a)
//
function test(i = 0, s = '') {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    const v = s + arr[i][j]
    if (arr[i + 1]) test(i + 1, v)
    else a.push(+v)
  }
}
```